# How to set reactive form field inside modal prior to opening?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been writing an appointment management system for just over a year now and during that time I have seen various angular updates i.e. angular 7 -> angular 8 -> 9 -> and now 10.

Each of the update have been the cause of some small breaking changes but were easy to fix.

I'm not 100% sure but I think the last update to angular 10 has broken my reactive forms inside my modal.

Brief description of angular component that has bug:
Bascially a component containing a datatable with the contents of a backend database table. When the user double clicks on one of the rows and modal is opened containing a reactive form to allow the user to edit the db record.

I am opening an ng-bootstrap modal with the following "open" function:

```
open(title:string, code:string, desc:string, type:string, message:string, updType:string) {

const modalRef = this.modalService.open(
  MediaModalComponent,
  {
    size: 'xl',
    windowClass: 'custom-class'
  });


  modalRef.componentInstance.title = title;
  modalRef.componentInstance.code = code;
  modalRef.componentInstance.desc = desc;
  modalRef.componentInstance.type = type;
  modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
  modalRef.componentInstance.updType = updType;

  this.mediaModal.mediaForm.patchValue({
    code: code,
    desc: desc,
    type: type,
    message: message
  });


  modalRef.componentInstance.refreshTable.subscribe(() => {
    this.getMediaData();
  })


}
```

Unfortunately, the patchValue function doesn't appear to be working because my form fields are null when the modal is opened.

I have used the following sources in attempt to find a solution myself before creating a new question:

- [angular 2 ng-bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195543/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-modal)
- [Angular 6 patchValue Not Setting..sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756515/angular-6-patchvalue-not-setting-sometimes)
- https://medium.com/@samichkhachkhi/setvalue-vs-patchvalue-angular-a64a55e912b8
- [Angular 8: PatchValue not working with ChangeDetector and UpdateValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899111/angular-8-patchvalue-not-working-with-changedetector-and-updatevalue)
- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Thanks in advance for any help as it is much appreciated. I was hoping to put the app live in next couple of weeks but only noticed this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is not Angular version and Reactive Forms. The only changes from Angular2 is about the .ts is more strict and that, at first, in subscribe to valueChanges, the value of res and the value of form.value.control and form.get('control').value was different.

I don't know there you define your `this.mediaModal.mediaForm`. Do you want to write

```
modalRef.componentInstance.mediaForm.pathValue(....)
```

If you create the formGroup in the ngOnInit, perhafs you need "wait" to Angular create the form. That's use a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    modalRef.componentInstance.mediaForm.pathValue(....)
})
```